# Infix expression evaluating error

Tags: java, jframe, calculator

I am trying to calculate infix expression such as 4*(2+3)-1. I used script engine manager. It worked on console application but when I used it on my JFrame there is eror when I clicked equals button.

```
private void equalsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        Object res = null;
        try {
            res = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(display1.getText());
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InfixCalculator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        result.setText((String) res);
    }
```

display1 shows infix expressions as following screen capture.

[image]

Error is as following:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is exactly what the error message tells you:
A `Double` cannot be cast to `String`.

On this line: `result.setText((String) res)`, you should try `result.setText(res)` which implicitely calls `result.setText(res.toString())`, and you might want to take a look at rounding as `Double` and `Float` do not have 100% precision.